# How to store data day by day from one month in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I have one question, how can I create a table which will store data and show them like this:

```
+-------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|January|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|..|31|
| Amount|  | 2|  |  | 1| 5| 7|  |  |..| 7|
| Income|  |30|  |  |10|98|75|  |  |..|89|
+-------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

etc... for every month and every year.

Of course Amount and Income have some dump data, to show only what I mean.

I think that table like that created in DB (A for amount, I for income):

```
+--+-------+----+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+
|ID|  month|year|01A|02A|...|31A| 01I|02I|...|31I|
|01|January|2015|   |  2|...|  7|    | 30|...| 89|
+--+-------+----+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+
```

is not optimal and look horrible. Creating table like this will take forever, and writing code to get any data, or put something there will take even more time. Thinking about February or other months that don't have 31 days is much worse... But there I can easily show empty fields for every month.

I thought that putting into DB something like this:

```
+--+------+------+----------+
|ID|amount|income|      date|
|01|     2|    30|02/01/2015|
+--+------+------+----------+
```

is much easier to implement, but much harder to show like the first table (mainly because of that empty fields).

So I have no idea how to create something like that in MySQL. Could you help me, please? Maybe some advice? 
If that will help: I'm programming in Symfony 2.6

Comment: the last one is the best schema for mySql. dont mix db storage logic with display logic

Comment: And store dates using a date data type

Comment: @Strawberry of course!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a relational database, linking amount, date and income. Or you could create a table like the third on your example, but separating the date in day, month and year, instead of putting all together. It's just an idea! Then it will be easier to retrieve the data from the database. I'll work on that! I'll be back as soon as possible.

Comment: separating the date is a bad idea

Comment: By keeping it as a date, you can use mysql date functions.  Split it out later if you need to.

Comment: @Dagon Yeah! I realized that! Thank you!

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Thank you for clarifying! PS.: this is the first time I'm glad for a downvote, because you guys took your time to explain why I'm wrong. This is extremely professional. Thank you!

Comment: @Eduardo dos Santos Almeida No problem :)  Another good point is the ease of using > and < with date fields.  e.g. WHERE mydate > '2015-05-11' AND mydate < '2015-07-11'.  Imagine how complicated that would be if you had split the date components in to separate fields.

Answer (score 1):

Make year (one to many) months, months (one to many) days, each day contains (one to many 
) income/amount, easy way is to use orm. Each income and amount can have created time use doctrine extensions for that. Also dont forget to relate them right way. Or the easiest thing on world make just table of income and amount with datetime and use doctrine query builder to fetch data by days or years...

Answer (score 1):

Use the latter schema, it's by far the best one.

And to convert it to something similar to the first, as an array of arrays in PHP you can use something like the following:

```
// Assume this function selects the rows you want according to last schema
$data = magically_fetch_all_data_from_database(
   "SELECT 
      id, 
      DAYOFMONTH(date) as day, 
      MONTH(date) as month, 
      YEAR(date) as year, 
      amount, 
      income 
    FROM 
      mytable"
  );

// Assume $data is an array of result rows
$end_data = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
  // Populate the month data for all days in the month once for each month
  if(!isset($end_data[$row['year']][$row['month']]) {
    // This will generate elements 1...[endofmonth] with 0 values
    $end_data[$row['year']][$row['month']] = 
      array_fill(
        1,
        cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $row['month'],$row['year']),
        array('amount'=>0, 'income'=>0)
      );
  }

  $end_data[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['day']] = array(
    'amount' => $row['amount'],
    'income' => $row['income']
  );
}

/* Resulting array:
 * array(
 *   [2015] => array(
 *     [1]  => array(
 *       [1] => array('amount'=>0, 'income'=>0),
 *       [2] => array('amount'=>0, 'income'=>0),
 *       ...
 *       [31] => array('amount'=>0, 'income'=>0)
 *     [2] => array(
 *       ...
 */
```

Of course, you'll have to customize it for your specific needs.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer! It was very inspiring! I've chaged it a little bit, by creating whole empty array, and then putting data from database into it.

Comment: @ptyskju if you find the answer to be the best fit, kindly make it the selected answer. Thanks!